# How to run Java GUI software without window manager in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, java

I have kiosk that it too slow. I 've tested Debian with XFACE and LTEX but they are really slow for the device. I should run Java FX GUI application.

Questions:

Can I run Java GUI application without windows manager? Something like that:

`startx /usr/bin/google-chrome`

If I can something like that, I think I can install just xorg and then run the software from the terminal. I think I don't have any other choice  except choosing fastest window manager like OpenBox , miwm, ratpoison... (I don't know which is the lightest and fastest but I will choose one of them)

Answer (score 0):

On debian 9.0 I've tested to run chrome, firefox, Java swing GUI application, Java FX GUI application. So solutions:

Installation (**xorg** and **openjdk**. Note: if you use openjdk and if you want to run fx application you must install **openjfx** too. If you use oracle HotSpot JDK javaFX libraries will be included automatically ):

```
apt-get install xorg
apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
apt-get install openjfx
```

chrome:
startx /usr/bin/chromium

firefox:

```
startx /usr/bin/firefox
```

java swing:

```
startx java -jar swing.jar
```

java FX:

```
xinit
Java -jar fx.jar
```